# Extend Odoo/Openerp datatype

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7, odoo-8

I want to extend an odoo datatype.
First I wanted to create a new datatype from scretch. This wasn't easy since odoo/openerp just don't know how to store that datatype.
So now I want to extend it.

```
from openerp import fields
class MyDataType(fields.Text):

    @classmethod
    def browse_my_data_type(self, value1, value2):
        result = value1 + value2
        if len(result) > 0:
            return result
        else:
            return False
```

I tried to use it. It's possible untill I want to call the `browse_my_data_type` method.

```
from openerp import models, fields, api        
import my_new_fields as my_fields       
class my_data_type_test(models.Model):
    _name = 'my.type.test'

    name =              fields.Char('Name')
    my_data_type =      my_fields.MyDataType("My Data Type")
    result =            fields.Char("Result", compute="_set_result")    

    @api.one
    def _set_result(self):
        result = self.my_data_type.browse_my_data_type("valuehere","anotheronehere")
        if result:
            self.result = result
        else:
            self.result = ""
```

I used this code to test the method. Sadly it gives me the error `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'browse_my_data_type'`
How can I make sure that he knows the method while using it this way? (`self.my_data_type.browse_my_data_type("valuehere","anotheronehere"`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code may be work:

```python
from openerp import fields


class MyDataType(fields._String):
    type = 'text'

    def browse_my_data_type(self, value1, value2):
        result = value1 + value2
        if len(result) > 0:
            return result
        else:
            return False
```